# Delete function using join in DQL

Tags: symfony, twig, dql

I'm trying to use the Doctrine QueryBuilder to perform the Delete function using query
I need to delete a record that is present in 2 tables ,
in TcTracks table the id is "id" and in TcWall teh id is "related_id"

my controller

```
  public function deleteAction(Request $request){
    $deleteQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->delete('TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks', 'd')
    ->innerJoin('TcprofileBundle:TcWall', 't', 'ON', 'd.id = t.related_id')
    ->where('d.id = :dId')
    ->setParameter('wId',  $request->get('related_id'))
    ->setParameter('dId',  $request->get('id'))
    ->getQuery();

    $deleted = $deleteQuery->getResult();

    $deleted->flush();
    return $this->render('TcPlayerBundle:Default:all.html.twig',array(
            'tracks' => $tracks
    ));

}
```

i need to delete same record in two tables , but its not performing for both tables, kindly help me

i'm getting error as

```
 Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line below:

```
->setParameter('wId',  $request->get('related_id'))
```

There is only `:dId` but no `:wId`.

Actually you did inner join by `'d.id = t.related_id'`, so `related_id` is not necessary to set any more.

Comment: it's only removing in 1 table, but in wall table its not removing

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `wID` parameter anywhere in query. In the same time you're using `->setParameter('wId',  $request->get('related_id'))` which is obsolete in this case. Try to remove this row and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is one-to-many realation with your entities

```
 TcPlayerBundle:TcTracks
```

and

```
TcprofileBundle:TcWall
```

if like that,you can do some like:

```
oneToMany:
        cascade: [remove]
```

in your config 'yourentity.orm.yml' file..

hope hlep you!